# bestseller how is it determined? Can it be based on number of orders instead of quantity?

Tags: best-seller

I just want to know how bestseller is determined. Is it simply based on the quantity of a product ordered? Can it be based on how many orders you have for the product?

For example Product 1 has a minimum qty to order of 500 and product 2 has no minimum qty to order. Say I order 500 orders of product 1 and then order 5 of product 2 in 2 separate orders to total 10 quantity. Could I have my bestseller section setup to show product 2 as the bestseller seeing as two orders were placed opposed to product 1 with 500?

Comment: I think there is no official answer for this. whichever you want to display in site, you can go with that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best sellers are reported on QTY ordered.
You can see this by looking at the SQL query generated from the sales reports. (note the SQL below may not be 100% true to core reports SQL as the SQL may have been altered by my [Dynamic Category Products](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-dynamic-category-products.html) extension but the crux of it will be the same)

```
SELECT 
    SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`,
    `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`,
    `order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`,
    `e`.`entity_type_id`,
    `e`.`attribute_set_id`,
    `e`.`type_id`,
    `e`.`sku`,
    `e`.`has_options`,
    `e`.`required_options`,
    `e`.`created_at`,
    `e`.`updated_at`
FROM
    `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items`
        INNER JOIN
    `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id
        AND `order`.state <> 'canceled'
        AND (`order`.created_at BETWEEN '2014-11-15 0:00:00' AND '2016-03-29')
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped' , 'configurable', 'bundle'))
        AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id
        AND e.entity_type_id = 4
        INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id
        AND product_website.website_id IN ('1')
WHERE
    (parent_item_id IS NULL)
        AND (e.entity_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            `e`.`entity_id`
        FROM
            `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
        GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`))
GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id`
HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0)
ORDER BY `ordered_qty` DESC , `order_items_name` ASC
```